# Ansible variables and tags

Tags: variables, automation, ansible, tags

I have a playbook that calls 2 roles with shared variables. I'm using the roles to create some level of abstraction layer.

The problem happens when I try to call the role with the tags and variables which belong to another role I get an error. Also, I tried to use dependencies didn't work
Let me paste the code here to explain.

I have a role --> KEYS. Where I save my API calls to my 2 different platforms. As listed I'm registering the result to the user_result1 and user_result2

### **first role  my_key.yml**

```
# tasks file for list_users

- name: List Users platform 1
  uri:
   url: 'http://myhttpage.example.platform1'
   method: GET
   headers:
     API-KEY: 'SOME_API_KEY'
  register: user_result1

- name: List Users platform 2
  uri:
   url: 'http://myhttpage.example.platform2'
   method: GET
   headers:
     API-KEY: 'SOME_API_KEY'
  register: user_result2
```

---

**Second role: list_users**

```
- name: List users platform1
  set_fact:
    user: '{{ user | default([]) + [ item.email ] }}'
  loop: "{{ user_result1.json }}"

- debug:
    msg: "{{ user }}"
  tags:
    - user_1

- name: List users Cloudflare
  set_fact:
    name: "{{ name | default([]) + [item.user.email] }}"
  loop: "{{ user_result2.result }}"

- debug:
    msg: "{{ name }}"
  tags:
    - user_2
```

---

**Playbook.yml**

```
---
- name: Users
  gather_facts: no
  hosts: localhost

  roles:
    - my_key
    - list_users
```

---

When I do the call without the --tags user_1 or user_2, it works fine.
However, when I do the call using the tags I got an error showing that variable user_result1 or user_result2 doesn't exist.

Any idea, please?

Thanks, Joe.

Comment: Regarding your question "_When I do the call without the --tags ..., it works fine. However, when I do the call using the tags ..._" you may have a look into [Tags](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html) and "_Ansible ... run the ... tasks tagged ... and skip the ... task that does not have that tag_". This means the tasks were varibales are registered or set become skipped and didn't run. Therefore the variables doesn't exist.

Comment: As pointed out by @U880D, what you get is totally expected. There is a special `always` tag you can use for tasks that should always run. Side note: you don't need those loops to extract the information you need, e.g. `{{ user_result1.json | map(attribute='email') }}` will return a list directly.

Comment: Thanks, guys. Much appreciated.  I'm quite new in Ansible, would you have an example that I could follow. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

(@U880D basically answered the question but the OCD me wants to mark this as fixed so I'm typing this)

This is working as expected - `--tags` basically let you skip every task except those with the tag specified. See the official doc for more info on tags:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html

Echoing what @zeitounator said - if you want something to run unconditionally when `--tag` is used tag them with `always`.